# UEFI boot not working on PackardBell easynote TV

Tags: boot, uefi

I have a PackardBell EasyNote TV43CM that has booted up fine up until now. Most of the time the firmware says that it failed to boot up from either the hard drive or the DVD drive but once in a while I do get a windows boot and then it says that windows did not shut down properly last time and gives the usual options to fix that but all of them fail and reboots the machine and then back to the same loop of failing to boot up from the drives.

Looking in the firmware (InsydeH20 rev 3.7) I see that it is UEFI boot only, doesn't offer me to enable legacy boot or anything of the sort, when I go into the boot tab of the firmware all I can do is rearrange the boot order, nothing else. I have also tried to boot from USB that contains both legacy and UEFI booting mechanism and only the UEFI boots.

Looking at the hard drive I see 3 partitions, here is the output from `fdisk -l`

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdf
Disk /dev/sdf: 698.7 GiB, 750156374016 bytes, 1465149168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xeedf850d

Device     Boot    Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdf1           2048   37750783   37748736    18G 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sdf2  *    37750784   37955583     204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdf3       37955584 1465145343 1427189760 680.6G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Too my understanding then the EFI system partition should be a Fat32 partition, there is no such partition. Looking inside these partitions then in the first partition I see the following content:

```
100_CR.DAT  D2D       ImageInfo.dat  RCD.DAT      SYSTEMCD.DAT
ACERBOOT    EFI       LPCD.dat       Restore.dat  System Volume Information
BOOT        FACTORY   Napp7.log      RyTools
BOOTMGR     Flag.log  NAPP.DAT       SOURCES
```

With the following as directories: `ACERBOOT, BOOT, D2D, EFI, FACTORY, RyTools, SOURCES, System Volume Information`

In the second partition I see the following:

```
Boot  bootmgr  Recovery  $RECYCLE.BIN  System Volume Information  Temp
```

With all of them being directories except `bootmgr`

The third partition contains Windows.

So I am wondering how is this machine supposed to be able to boot? It can only boot UEFI, but doesn't have a Fat32 partition with the EFI directory in it, and the disk has the MBR partition scheme, not GPT.

The computer has Win7 on it and I have tried to boot of both Win7 and Win10 installations disks and tried to fix the bootup but both fail, the Win7 says it is not compatible (I guess it tries to fix a MBR boot) and the Win10 just says it failed.

Any ideas on how to make this machine boot again without reinstalling the OS?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked for dead sectors on the disk?
If you are having boot errors for a while you should see if there is something wrong with your disk.

What i recomend is to have backups handy to prevent this cases...

Hiren's BootCD is a nice program to check for dead sectors and try a repair.

Comment: I had put it through the Seagate SeaTools test and that found nothing wrong.